# What is the best way to use Ninject with MVC 3 and how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

What is the best way to use Ninject with MVC 3 and **how** ?

It is using a controller factory ? or using NinjectHttpApplication ?

How to get ninject for MVC 3 ? Ive looked around but i can't seem to figure out how to get the required ..mvc.dll

Any exemples would be helpful to me and others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best and simplest way to get Ninject for MVC 3 is adding the NuGet package **Ninject.MVC3** using the NuGet Package Manager from within Visual Studio.

This will set up everything for you, add an `App_Start` folder to your application which contains `NinjectMVC3.cs`. At this point everything is already hooked up as Controller Factory thanks to `WebActivator` - you can just add your bindings in `RegisterServices()` or of course put them in a separate module.

Comment: What the avantage in putting them in seperate module, also what a module ?

Comment: @Rushino: Ninject modules allow you to have a set of bindings encapsulated in their own class - for a complete explanation see this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056409/what-is-the-intention-of-ninject-modules

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way is to exted from **NinjectHttpApplication** in the global.asax and then override the **IKernel CreateKernel()** method

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication {
  ...
  ...

  protected override IKernel CreateKernel() {
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    // Register services with Ninject DI Container    
    kernel.Bind<IFileSystemService>().To<FileSystemService>();
    return kernel;
  }

  ...
}
```