# DI Modules in ASP.NET Core built-in DI system

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have been using NInject for some time, and now I will be starting a project in Asp.net core. Seems [NInject cannot be used with Asp.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/1977871). So now my question is does Asp.net core provide any [di modules just as NInject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056509/1977871) or other di containers provide?

Comment: You misinterpreted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788637/continued-ninject-support-in-asp-net-mvc-6/32797105#32797105) answer. The answer clearly states that Ninject *can* be used.

Answer (score 13):

ASP.NET Core doesn't provide any module support at all. It is designed to be a simple out-of-the-box container where 3rd parties IoC container can plug-in.

So there are no auto-registration, assembly scannings, decorators, interceptors or modules. If you want them, you need to use 3rd party frameworks (AutoFac, StructureMap etc.).

3rd party libraries do register using Registration methods, which are called like `services.AddXxx()` in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public static class MyLibraryServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddScoped<IMyService,MyService>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

It is preferred way to register libraries (cause it doesn't depend on any IoC container except for the built-in `IServiceCollection`, which 3rd party containers use too when plugged in ASP.NET Core), for stuff like "business logic library" there isn't really such a thing (where modules were useful before).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other good answers, you can use e.g. [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html). It's a brilliant DI-container that supports .Net Core (and ASP.Net Core as well). See details of how to use it with .Net Core [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try ServiceCollection.Extensions.Modules from nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceCollection.Extensions.Modules/)

Answer (score -6):

Asp.Net Core provides out of the box DI framework, it allows you to add an object for each resolve request, per Http Request or a singleton.
All of this is done in the `ConfigureServices` method
ex:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Your configuration

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

You can read more about it here

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

Comment: It doesn't really answer the OPs question if there is a module support, where the modules is defined in each class library and does it registrations there and the main app only loads the module class during bootstrapping

Comment: How come it is not answering the question? the question is about asp.net core support for a DI, and the answer is it has a ready made one, so what would be the answer from your POV? and why should we suggest another DI like ninject if it is already there OOB?

Comment: No, the question is not about ASP.NET Core Support for DI, the OP knows it is there. He specifically asked about modules. Modules are classes placed in the library which perform registrations in contrast to performing the registrations in the mail application. You can read here https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel about the modules in Ninject. Other IoC have it too (CastleWindsor, Autofac, Unity Container). But ASP.NET Core's DI doesn't have that for the reasons I pointed in my answer